# What is the difference between unit and dimensions?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

If I say Height of a block = 2m, then would "Height" be called as a dimension

Answer (score 2):

Casually I would say the dimensions are `MASS`, `LENGTH` and `TIME` (and others). A unit is a metric (yardstick) to measure said dimensions. So one meter (unit) is used to quantify a specific length (dimension).

This allows the combination of dimensions through multiplication and division to derive other units such as `Speed = Meter/Second => LENGTH/TIME`

Comment: I don't really like this answer because there's no reason there have to be only three dimensions.

Comment: Agreed. 7 fundamental dimensions. Principle is correct however.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that a dimension is a degree of freedom - a quantity or a quality by which a system can vary?

Comment: I was starting simple here.